# Angular trackBy not working in nested *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, angularjs-track-by

My component is some what like

```
<div class="users-list" *ngIf="datasetPermission !== undefined">
    <div *ngFor="let userpermission of datasetPermission; trackBy : trackByFn">
      <span *ngFor="let user of userpermission.users">
        <span *ngIf="user">
        <span class="shared-user"><span>{{user.emailId}}</span><span ><span  class="close icon-key" style=" padding: 0;" (click)="viewPermission($event,userpermission.permissionType,user)"></span><span class="close" style=" padding: 0;" (click)="removeUser(user)">×</span></span></span>
      </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

trackBy function as

```
    public trackByFn(index, userpermission) {
      console.log(userpermission.permissionType);
      return userpermission.permissionType;
    }
```

Inside permissions I've array of users who are assigned to this permission.I can update users from x <> y permission set.
when I'm updating the datasetPermission array or adding new element to it it is updating the order of dataset being updated/added.

I've gone through various posts but yet to find something useful.
Am I doing something incorrect here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is wrong implementation for `trackByFn`.

`trackBy` `function` always accept two parameters `index` and current `item` and function must return the unique identifier.

So your `function` should be like -

```
public trackByFn(index, userpermission) {
    return userpermission.id; //check what unique property you have in permission class.
  }
```

Comment: tried but not working, still I can see reflections in DOM

Comment: what you are returning from the function ? Share your code please.

Comment: You have another ngFor for users. So better to write another `trackBy` `function` for users too.